# I want to unsubscribe to a mod, but in doing so it causes the game to malfunction. Is there a way to fix that?

Tags: mods, starbound

The mod i want unsubscribed without malfunctioning the game(Starbound) is the avonian mod. My brother downloaded it before and i don't want it anymore. Its a race mod that already causes certain npcs to die when interacted with in quests. And when its unsubscribed it cause the player to be teleport back to the ship when the character moves to the right. I have already let the mod developer know but just in case im asking for others help.

Comment: When you say it makes the game malfunction, do you mean that your old saves break or that new games break?

Comment: it's highly possible the mod has already altered your save as such there may be unforeseen consequences if Starbound doesn't do what Skyrim or Fallout does in regards to mod removal (even they don't guarantee consequence free mod removal). sometimes it might be best to bite the bullet and unintall the game entirely and redownload a clean version

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of mods will modify your save too much to be fixed, and they'll often say so on their download page. There are certain inventory editors which can be used to save and edit your inventory - my best suggestion would be to use one of these to save your inventory and then create a new world after deleting the mod. Using /admin should allow you to skip through your pre-completed quests, and you can spawn some ship upgrade modules to get back your upgraded ship. This leaves the only obstacle as gaining crew members. 
If you follow this method, I strongly suggest you reinstall the game beforehand, or your universe will be the same, which will cause bugs.